# Show html content on top of android view

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am developing android phone gap app.
I have design HTML page & in that call android layout which contain buttons in linear layout from plugin.

Now I am opening menu on click of device menu button. Menu is design in HTL `<div>` tag.

When I open menu my android view is overlapping on menu. I want menu will hide android layout.

I also set `z-index` for menu. Can we set z index for android layout so that android view goes back of menu.

Please help

Comment: Your question is bit tough to understand. Can you elaborate properly?

Comment: In html page I add view of audio player which is design in android       native.(play stop & sound button)This player is design in linear layout         & I am passing url from htmp page using plugin.Now I open menu screen using phone menu button but on menu page(design in html div tag) my audio player is overlapping.I want to show menu page on top of audio player.How to solve this